# Google Analytics Custom Dimension Not Being Set

Tags: google-analytics, dimensions

I've recently upgraded our site to use Universal Analytics and am trying to get some custom dimensions to work.  However, no custom dimension data appears to be logged.  Below is an example of my code.

```
ga('create', 'UA-XXXXX', 'test.com');
ga('send', 'pageview');
ga('set', 'dimension1', '149377');
```

Do I need to set custom dimensions before sending pageview?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

A dimension is sent along with the either a page view or an event. It won't get sent by itself. So you should switch the order of the 'send' and 'set', then look in the network to see the page view call and you should see the dimension as one of the parameters.

Note that you will see the dimension data in google analytics with a delay of a day or so.

Comment: "Note that you will see the dimension data in google analytics with a delay of a day or so." Thank you so much for that info — I was losing my mind.

Comment: When you say the dimension information is delayed, does that mean even defining a dimension after you've already been collecting it will be delayed as well? In my case, I have `userId` I've sending for quite some time and am just now defining the custom dimension in analytics.

Comment: God I wish the delay thing was documented on their site. The old Custom Variables show up immediately on traffic in a custom report, new dimensions not even after a couple hours. Lot of people probably pulling out hair over this.

Answer (score 9):

I had the same problem, took me a while to find out its cause...

That's correct by the way, that is **you must do the SET before the SEND**.

Here is the official documentation (see section "Collection"):

> [...] Unlike other types of data, custom dimensions and metrics are sent to Google Analytics as parameters attached to other hits, like pageviews, events, or ecommerce transactions. As such, custom dimension or metric values need to be set before a tracking call is made in order for that value to be sent to Google Analytics.
>
> For example, to set a custom dimension value, your code might look like this:

```
ga('create', 'UA-XXXX-Y', 'auto');

// Set value for custom dimension at index 1.
ga('set', 'dimension1', 'Level 1');

// Send the custom dimension value with a pageview hit.
ga('send', 'pageview');
```

Cfr. https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2709828?hl=en

Comment: The 'dimension1' value set here will be associated with every event or the first event it gets?

Comment: @anurag the dimension1 value set here will be sent every time the line send pageview at the bottom is called.

Comment: what if there are two more events below send pageview like
ga('send', 'event', 'productViews', 'views', productName, 1);
ga('send', 'event', 'search', 'click', searchterm);
So here, will dimension1 set for the above two events as well?
Basically my requirement is to set custom dimensions for all the events which happen on that page, but I don't want to modify all the ga calls

Comment: It depends on the scope chosen for the custom dimension: "When custom dimensions are processed, scope determines to which hits a particular custom dimension value will be applied. Scope determines which hits will be associated with a particular custom dimension value. There are four levels of scope: product, hit, session, and user" (see https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2709828?hl=en ). 

In your case, I would suggest using a Session scope, so that custom dimension value is applied to all hits in a single session.

Comment: thanks for the explanation, yes Session level scope suits me the best.