# How would you track in GA if a browser supports a certain feature?

Tags: google-analytics, seo

I'm trying to figure out how to track a specific variable for Google Analytics, i. e. browserSupportsFeatureX: true/false

I am a bit overwhelmed with all the hit types in google analytics. I want to only track these things only once per session but I don't think there's a session hit type.

Seems like I first have to define a metric and or dimension like above but what exactly do I send over? If I send a pageview over it'll track it for every page, which I don't want.

`ga('set', 'webcomponents1', 'Level 1');

  ga('send', 'pageview', {
    'webcomponents1':  supportsWebComponents
  });`

Comment: You would use some kind of feature detection to see if webcomponents are enabled and then store the info in a custom dimension, which makes the q. basically a duplicate of this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37827400/google-analytics-custom-variable-is-not-working

Answer (score 0):

You can indeed set a session-level custom dimension. This is created at the property level in Google Analytics, under Custom Definitions in the Admin section. You'll get an index number for the dimension.

Suppose you created a new dimension called "Web Components Enabled", and it was given the index "1". You then refer to it as `dimension1` in your Google Analytics calls.

So, you would first need some JavaScript code that detects web components support. I found this [here](https://github.com/webcomponents/webcomponentsjs/issues/26#issuecomment-159806570):

```
var webComponentsSupported = (
    'registerElement' in document &&
    'import' in document.createElement('link') &&
    'content' in document.createElement('template'));
```

Then, before your pageview or any events are sent by your code, invoke:

```
if (webComponentsSupported) {
    ga('set', 'dimension1', 'Yes');
} else {
    ga('set', 'dimension1', 'No');
}
```

This will give you a "Yes" or "No" for all sessions (and all activities within a session) on whether or not web components are supported when you include the custom dimension "Web Components Enabled" in your reporting.

Optionally you could omit the `else` clause and simply assume they're not enabled when the dimension has no value / is absent.