# GTM how to set custom dimension to GA page view?

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager, google-datalayer, custom-dimensions

I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23528368/google-analytics-custom-dimension-not-being-set) mentioned that the custom dimension value must set before `ga('send', 'pageview');`

But what if I use Google Tag Manager?

```
dataLayer.push({
    'postId': '{{ $post->id }}',
    'userId': '{{ auth()->user()->id }}',
});
```

I've set up the data layer variable to GTM to trigger GA. But when I look at the GA report, and filter by custom dimension, it's not working.

I checked with the debug, **Tags Fired On This Event** shows below

[image: GTM chrome plugin]

How do I set the custom dimension before it sent to GA pageview?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to define the datalayer BEFORE loading of the GTM script.

Example to place at the top of the page before GTM is loaded:

```
<script>
  dataLayer = [{
   'postId': '{{ $post->id }}',
   'userId': '{{ auth()->user()->id }}',
  }];
</script>
```

When you do this, the data is available right away.

Another thing you can do is instead of using the datalayer, if the pages are rendered server-side, is to use  tags with the postid and userid as values. This will ensure they're loaded before GTM.

https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/devguide#adding-data-layer-variables-to-a-page