# Custom dimension not being set

Tags: google-analytics, custom-dimensions

I've got myself a bit of a head scratcher here, for me anyway, as I'm a bit new to all this.

I have WP a site that has its GA snippet inserted with Google Site Kit.
There is a plugin that, when a user registers, sets the users ID to a custom dimension.

The code to execute this 'set' has been added to the WP footer with the `add_action('wp_footer')` command.

The code looks like this:

```
<script type=\"text/javascript\" id=\"set-google-id-dimension\">
    document.addEventListener(\"readystatechange\", event => {              
        if (event.target.readyState === \"complete\") {
            try{
                gtag('event', 'registration', {'dimension1': '".$client."'});
            }catch(e){
                try{
                    ga(function() {
                        // Logs an array of all tracker objects
                        var trackers = ga.getAll();
                        var firstTracker = trackers[0];
                        console.log('tracker: '+firstTracker.get('name'));
                        ga(firstTracker.get('name')+\".set\",\"dimension1\" ,\"".$client."\");
                    });
                }catch(e){
                    console.log('GA and GTAG not defined');
                }
            }
        }
    });
</script>
```

For ease of reading, I've stripped out the PHP, but this is being echoed out in the footer.

Why the GTAG and GA command?  Both analytics are being output in the console, though the site owner does not know why as "they only use Google Site Kit".

Now, this code works on the dev site that I control (and I've set it up to mimic the live site as best as possible):

[image]

However, when on the "live" site, the dimension is never set, even though I can see the 'set' command being executed (ignore the timestamps in the console, I forgot to screenshot before navigating away from the site and had to go back and reload the page):

[image]

[image]

The live site does not use the default tracker, hence the `ga.getAll()` call to access the tracker information.
From what I can see, everything should work fine.

I understand that from reviewing this question
[Google Analytics Custom Dimension Not Being Set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23528368/google-analytics-custom-dimension-not-being-set)
that the 'set' needs to come before the 'send'.

I'm not sure how to accomplish this though since the plugin does not send the pageview to GA, from what I understand, that's Google Site Kit.  I have contemplated adding a 2nd pageview send when this plugins code is loaded (it is only executed immediately after a registration and never again), but that would skew the page hits.

This site has had a myriad of "admins" over the years, so I wouldn't be surprised if there was something buried in one of the plugins causing a conflict somewhere.  At one point I thought it was a timing issue, so I had the function load every 50 milliseconds checking for 'ga' to be defined, then execute the 'set' command (with a limit to 35 iterations), but the issue was the same (could set the command execute in the console, but the dimension did not reflect the value).

Any advice I can get to debug and get to the root cause would be of great assistance to me.  Please ask any questions you need and I will respond as quickly as possible.

Answer (score 0):

It seems a bit complex as a situation so understanding how it works and why there is `gtag` and `ga` at the same time is not easy to understand.

In any case, assuming that everything is working, what you can do is **not to send a second pageview** but **send a dedicated event** (by setting `non-interaction` to `true`) in this way you do not alter any information in Google Analytics and you can pass to the platform the data you are interested in (dimension1).

Comment: The gtag and ga are there because when initially implemented, no-one could tell me what version of Google Analytics they were using, so I tried both.  The gtag never executed, it was always the ga, so I can remove that now.  I'll try the dedicated event and get an update soon, thanks!

Comment: Perfect, let me know!

Comment: Unfortunately, adding the non-interaction event didn't seem to make a difference.  I can see the 'set' and 'send' commands in the analytics console with no apparent 'errors' being output, but the dimension value remains the same as clientId.  (the gtag code has also been removed since it is superfluous).

Comment: non-interaction serves you for not alter any information in Google Analytics not to change dimension value... It could be depend on time you try to get that information, try onload.

Comment: Apologies for being so late in getting back to you on this, changed the code to onload, and various document state changes, but it still remains that the dimension value is not reflected as being value we are 'setting' in our command